# Legendary items pool of power

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, powers

When a magical item became a Legendary Item and then became a major Artifact, gains

> it gains the suite of base legendary abilities and can have up to three additional legendary abilities. By selecting the legendary item universal path ability more than once, a mythic creature can transform a normal legendary item into either a minor artifact (if the character chooses it a second time) or a major artifact (if the character chooses it a third time). A minor artifact legendary item can have up to six additional legendary abilities, and gains the difficult to destroy ability (see below). A major artifact legendary item can have up to 10 additional legendary abilities and gains the difficult to destroy ability.

Now a wielder can use hits

> Legendary Power: All legendary items contain a pool of power—at least two uses that recharge each day. This power is called legendary power, and it works differently than mythic power. Any creature bearing the item can expend the items uses of legendary power, whether or not that creature is mythic. These uses of legendary power can be expended only to activate the legendary item’s abilities. If the item’s bearer isn’t bonded to the item, she can expend the item’s legendary power only to use its legendary surge ability.

For example the wearer can use the Legendary Surge of the legendary item two times during a battle and then stop.
The question is: Now a wielder can use almost 13 (10 + base) legendary powers from the item but only for two times a day, *"a pool of power—at least two uses "*. Who decide the number of uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Item's Abilities Decide.

From that we can see that all legendary items start with a base of 2 uses for their legendary power. If we then continue reading the abilities listed for [Legendary Items](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Legendary%20Item%20Abilities&Category=Legendary%20Items), we'll see:

> **Powerful:** An item with this ability has two additional uses of legendary power per day. This ability can be taken up to three times. The item must be a minor or major artifact to take this a second time, and a major artifact to take this a third time. This is a persistent ability.

This expands the number of uses that you have, hence the "at least two uses".

Of course, a GM can always adjust the number of uses an item has before taking that ability, but this is how legendary items usually gain more uses.

Comment: So the 1st wielder (or the creator/bounded creature) of the Legendary item major artifact uses three of the 10 Legendary abilities to expand the Legendary Pool of power from 2 to 8! Correct?

Comment: The creator does.